# What happens if a monitor's refresh rate is different to X's refresh rate?

Tags: centos, x-windows, refresh-rate

I have a dual-screen system running on CentOS Linux using two industrial grade LCD touch screens. I currently have the following line set in my xorg.conf under the "Display" subsection of the Screen section:

> Modes     "1280x1024_60.00"

The Xorg.log also has the following:

> (II) IEGD(1): Keeping user defined mode: 1280x1024_60.00

This all seems well and good, but I recently noticed in the screen's menu that it is running at 1280x1024 at 75Hz.

I have yet to dig up the documentation on the touch screen to work out if 75Hz is in fact its minimum refresh rate, but I was wondering - does this cause an issue? All signs point to Xorg and the graphics driver considering the refresh rate of the screen to be 60Hz. What happens if there is a discrepancy between the graphics driver's assumed refresh rate and the screen's actual refresh rate?

I can find plenty of stuff online that talks about differences between video game FPS and screen refresh rates. Does that apply in this instance too (i.e. is the effect of `app : screen` ratio the same as `driver : screen` ratio) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because Xorg keeps a user-supplied modeline doesn't mean that it will necessarily be *used*. If there is a better fit that is not overridden, Xorg will use it instead.

Comment: I wondered that myself. Is there some string I can look for in the Xorg log that will tell me which mode it chooses?